# Identify when a change to a field has happened in a particular field over the last 30 days. If found insert record in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

On a daily basis I will be appending a table from one database to another table in another database, and while doing so I will be storing the date timestamp of every import.

Below is a sample table of the data:

| Customer | RelationshipCode | RelatedCustomer | DateImported |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3374 | 26 | 3912 | 18/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 26 | 3913 | 18/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 22 | 3413 | 18/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 21 | 3503 | 18/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 21 | 3504 | 18/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 21 | 4191 | 18/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 26 | 7567 | 18/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 21 | 6191 | 18/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 26 | 3912 | 19/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 26 | 3913 | 19/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 22 | 3413 | 19/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 21 | 3503 | 19/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 26 | 3504 | 19/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 26 | 7567 | 19/02/2021 |
| 3374 | 21 | 1234 | 19/02/2021 |

As you can see from the data above RelatedCustomer 4191 is no longer a relation to Customer 3374 on 19/02/2021. Furthermore, RelatedCustomer 3504 is still a relation to customer 3374, however relationship code changed from 21 to 26. For the mentioned cases above I would like to insert these two records in a separate table with the date of change being 18/02/2021 or 19/02/2021 (Whichever would be the easiest to extract).

Also on 19/02/2021 a new relationship was created for RelatedCustomer 1234 to Customer 3374. In this case I don't need to insert this record in a separate table.

Further to this please note that I want to check the dates from (date - 30 days) to today.

Comment: Agreed...apologies. I am using SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

So your first query would be something like

```
INSERT INTO myTable1 (columns...)
SELECT columns...
FROM mytable o
WHERE o.DateImported = '2021-02-14'
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM mytable i
                 WHERE o.RelatedCustomer = i.RelatedCustomer
                   AND o.Customer = i.Customer
                   AND DateAdd(day, 1, o.DateImported) = i.DateImported
                )
```

and the second would be similar:

```
INSERT INTO myTable2 (columns...)
SELECT columns...
FROM mytable o
WHERE o.DateImported = '2021-02-14'
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM mytable i
                 WHERE o.RelatedCustomer = i.RelatedCustomer
                   AND o.Customer = i.Customer
                   AND DateAdd(day, 1, o.DateImported) = i.DateImported
                )
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM mytable i
                 WHERE o.RelatedCustomer = i.RelatedCustomer
                   AND o.Customer = i.Customer
                   AND o.RelationshipCode= i.RelationshipCode
                   AND DateAdd(day, 1, o.DateImported) = i.DateImported
                )
```